# After rendering one chart when trying to render a new one chart.js gives "Check that a complete date adapter is provided."

Tags: chart.js

I have made a script which renders a graph with multiple lines and dates, I can run the script once perfectly fine but when trying to run it a second time it give an error: "Error: This method is not implemented: Check that a complete date adapter is provided.". I couldn't find anything about it that fits my situation.

```
[enter image description here][1]const {
MessageEmbed,
MessageAttachment
} = require("discord.js");    
const {
ChartJSNodeCanvas
} = require("chartjs-node-canvas");
const canvas = require('canvas'); // important
var groupArray = require('group-array');
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios');
require('chartjs-adapter-moment')
const generateCanva = async (labels, datas, names, interaction) => {
const renderer = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
    width: 800,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColour: "white"
});
parsedLabels = []
if (Array.isArray(labels[0])) {
    for (alabel in labels) {
        parsedLabels = labels[alabel].reduce(
            (acc, item) => {
                return acc.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item]
            },
            [...parsedLabels]
        )
    }
} else {
    parsedLabels = labels
}

parsedLabels = parsedLabels.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(b) - new Date(a);
}).reverse();
parsedLabelsDate = []
for (x in parsedLabels) {
    parsedLabelsDate.push(new Date(parsedLabels[x]))
}
chartObject = {
    type: "line", // Show a bar chart
    backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
            }
        }
    },

    data: {
        labels: parsedLabelsDate,
        datasets: [],
    },
}

colors = ['rgb(240,128,128)', 'rgb(240,230,140)', 'rgb(152,251,152)', 'rgb(0,206,209)', 'rgb(135,206,250)', 'rgb(238,130,238)']

if (Array.isArray(labels[0])) {
    for (var i in labels) {
        parcedDatas = []
        for (x in datas[i]) {
            parcedDatas.push({
                x: new Date(labels[i][x]),
                y: datas[i][x]
            })
        }
        dataset = {
            label: names[i],
            data: parcedDatas,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: colors[i],
            tension: 0.1
        }
        console.log(dataset)
        chartObject.data.datasets.push(dataset)
    }

} else {
    dataset = {
        label: interaction.author.username,
        data: datas,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1
    }
    chartObject.data.datasets.push(dataset)
}
const image = await renderer.renderToBuffer(
    // Build your graph passing option you want
    chartObject
);
return new MessageAttachment(image, "graph.png");
};
```

Comment: Couldnt attach images so here they are:
working graph:
https://gyazo.com/1112ba41c781d6f59a27b0f6be2908af

error:
https://gyazo.com/51d703f144dbf3be497188a927df51f5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include adapters and plugins with ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68608799/how-to-include-adapters-and-plugins-with-chartjs)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335353/chartjs-time-cartesian-axis-adapter-and-date-library-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by moving:

```
const renderer = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
width: 800,
height: 300,
backgroundColour: "white"
});
```

Outside of the function.